# Transpose of Eigenvector Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does the statement:
$$v^TA=v^T$$
Imply
$$Av = v$$

Where A is an nxn matrix and v a vector.

Comment: No. It's equivalent to $A^\top v=v$

Comment: I transposed the first equation, not the second

Comment: For an example, let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $v^TA=v^T$, but $Av = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @b00nheT I realized my error, and hence deleted my first comment.

Comment: [The transpose of a product is the product of the transposes in reverse order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440305/how-to-prove-abt-bt-at)

Comment: Surely that example doesn't apply as $Av =/= v$ in this case.