# Problem in proving \begin{eqnarray*} \left \lVert Ax-y\right\rVert^{2} &=& x^{T} A^{T} A x -2 y^{T} A x + y^{T} y \end{eqnarray*}

Tags: vector-analysis, normed-spaces

I begin with doing
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left \lVert Ax-y\right\rVert^{2} &=& (Ax-y)^{T}(Ax-y)
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left \lVert Ax-y\right\rVert^{2} &=& (x^{T}A^{T}-y^{T})(Ax-y)
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left \lVert Ax-y\right\rVert^{2} &=& x^{T} A^{T} A x - y^{T} A x -x^{T} A^{T} y+ y^{T} y
\end{eqnarray*}

So my doubt is how to show \begin{eqnarray*}
\ y^{T} A x=x^{T} A^{T} y
\end{eqnarray*}

because if it is true my proof will be completed.

Comment: yes that is a well known fact about transpose. you can prove it by the definition of transpose and matrix mulitplication.

Comment: are you talking about (AB)'=B'A'

Comment: $y^T Ax$ is a 1x1 matrix, or simply a number, so taking the transpose will give you the same thing. But the transpose is precisely $x^TA^Ty$. Hence, they are equal

Comment: more generally https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440305/how-to-prove-abt-bt-at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y^t Ax$ is just the dot product between $Ax$ and $y$, regarded as column vectors. Also, $x^tA^t y = (Ax)^t y$ is the dot product between $y$ and $Ax$.