# Why is $x^T(A^Ty)=(Ax)^Ty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, transpose

In a book I am reading orthogonality of the null space and the row space is proven as follows:

For any $x\in ker(A)$ and any y satisfying $A^Ty$ $$x^T(A^Ty)=(Ax)^Ty=0^Ty=0$$
The step that I am not clear on is why $x^T(A^Ty)=(Ax)^Ty$? First why is the transpose distributive and second why does A appear on the right on the right hand side of the equation and on the left on the left hand side?

Comment: [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440305/how-to-prove-abt-bt-at)

Comment: Generally for matrices $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$

Answer (score 1):

@SahibaArora has linked you to [a proof on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440305/how-to-prove-abt-bt-at) that $x^TA^T=(Ax)^T$. By associativity, $x^T(A^Ty)=(x^TA^T)y=(Ax)^Ty$.