# If $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices, and given that $B$ is symmetric, then is the matrix $C=\text{trn}(A)BA$ necessarily symmetric?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, transpose

> If $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices, and given that $B$ is symmetric, then is the matrix $C=\text{trn}(A)BA$ necessarily symmetric?

I know that given the symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, then $AB$ is symmetric if and only if $A$ and $B$ follow commutative property of multiplication, i.e., if $AB = BA$... but is that the case here?

Comment: It is not clear what $C=\text{trn}(A)BA$ is supposed to mean. Is trn your notation for the trace?

Comment: I assume $trn(A)$ means the transpose of $A$, usually denoted $A^T$. Do you know that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$?

Comment: Just use the definition of a symmetric matrix. What is $C^T$?

Comment: what is trn(A)?

Comment: Firstly your definition of symmeteric is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a matrix is called symmetric if it's equal to its own transpose,ie:$X^{T}=X$

As noted by the other users in the comments, also recall that [$(PQR)^T=R^TQ^TP^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440305/how-to-prove-abt-bt-at)

$$(A^TBC)^T=\cdots=\cdots$$

Can you finish?

Comment: trn(C)trn(B)A ?

Comment: @MrReddit thats correct. Now what does the question say about the transpose of $B$?

Comment: it says that B is symmetric which means it's equal to its own transpose

Comment: Ah okay i get it now thanks alot :)