# What is the specific reason 2 matrices flip after taking their transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the identity $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$. I tried to research the exact reason why this is the case and could not find a good description. My professor said the reason is because "you ought to put on your socks before your shoes" which did not really resonate with me...

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1280243/680927).

Comment: Simple: Because the dimensions need to match.
More Advanced: Because dualization is contravariant.
Both of these get elaborated on in the linked question.

Comment: @Thorgott that is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Azif00 Beautiful.

Comment: Socks and shoes work for the inverse $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, not for the transpose, that is why it did not resonate. If you put on socks first, and then shoes, the order reverses when taking them off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of defining the transpose is the matrix $M$ that satisfies
$\langle Mx, y \rangle = \langle x, A y \rangle $ for all $x,y$.

It is not hard to show that $M=A^T$ where $A^T$ is defined in the usual way.

Consequently, $ \langle (AB)^Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, ABy \rangle = \langle A^Tx, By \rangle = \langle B^T A^Tx, y \rangle $ and hence $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense using an inner product.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but to add to the answer above, the adjoint of a linear operator $T$ on a vector space $V$, denoted $T^*$, is the unique function such that
$$\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, T^*w \rangle$$
for all $v, w \in V$.

It is straightforward to show that $T^* $ is a linear map, that $(TS)^* = S^*T^\ast$ for any other linear operator $S$ on $V$, and that the matrix representation of $T^\ast$ with respect to any orthonormal basis of $V$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to that basis. In the case of a real $n \times n$ matrices, using the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, these results imply $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.

The book "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler covers these results, for example.